# How to convert seconds to hh:mm:ss format from output of another shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, busybox, openwrt

everyone

here is my script

```
/bin/wstalist | grep 'uptime'
```

Which is return value like `"uptime": 3456,` yes there's a `,` coming with output.

These number are seconds. I want to convert it to hh:mm:ss format. and want it to be simple cause it will running by a router(busybox) in every minute.

So the problem is I don't know how.

Can someone help me? please.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to accomplish?  Are you asking how to take a number of seconds and covert that to hours/minutes/seconds (e.g., 3456 = 00:57:36)?

Comment: yes, it is. exactly as you said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
line=$(/bin/wstalist | grep 'uptime')
sec=${line##* }
sec=${sec%%,}
h=$(( $sec / 3600 ))
m=$(( $(($sec - $h * 3600)) / 60 ))
s=$(($sec - $h * 3600 - $m * 60))
if [ $h -le 9 ];then h=0$h;fi
if [ $m -le 9 ];then m=0$m;fi
if [ $s -le 9 ];then s=0$s;fi
echo $h:$m:$s
```

Comment: That's what exactly I'm looking for! thank you very much!

Comment: after I ran it for a while. I think I found bugs.
1. hh:mm:ss format sometime show as xx:xxx:xx or xx:xx:xxx
2. it appear to be a wrong value so many times eg 00:00:32 event if /bin/wstalist returns so much value more than that.

can you please look into it?

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/bash

# Here's the output from your command
output='"uptime": 3456,'

# Trim off the interesting bit
seconds="$(echo "${output}" | awk '{ print $2 }' | sed -e 's/,.*//')"

readonly SECONDS_PER_HOUR=3600
readonly SECONDS_PER_MINUTE=60

hours=$((${seconds} / ${SECONDS_PER_HOUR}))
seconds=$((${seconds} % ${SECONDS_PER_HOUR}))
minutes=$((${seconds} / ${SECONDS_PER_MINUTE}))
seconds=$((${seconds} % ${SECONDS_PER_MINUTE}))

printf "%02d:%02d:%02d\n" ${hours} ${minutes} ${seconds}
```

Comment: thanks man. but it doesn't work for me. but I do appreciate your help!